# Webfont Trade Gothics not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, font-face

I have this code which is meant to make webfonts work properly in every browser:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TradeGothic-BoldCondensedNo20';
    src: url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.eot?')  format("embedded-opentype"),
         url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.woff')  format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

However, it is still not working in IE8 and older.

Comment: Have you tried absolute path for the files?

Comment: in the [fontspring syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax) they use 'myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix', maybe the #iefix could help in this case?

Comment: @r3bel already tried but same result

Comment: @jycr753 also for this solution, already tried but same result

Answer (score 2):

IE8 doesn’t understand the `format()` specifier; here’s the hack that I tend to use:

```
src: url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.eot');
src: local('☺'),
     url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.eot?')  format("embedded-opentype"),
     url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.woff')  format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/tradegothic/trade-gothic-lt-std-bold-condensed-no-20.ttf')  format('truetype');
```

IE8 and earlier will drop the entire second `src` rule, leaving you (with any luck) with a working webfont.

You can also probably take out the EOT line in the second `src` rule, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the type of file into the htaccess.. I had the same problem not long ago and this solve it...

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
```

you can see the docs for Addtype [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)

Answer (score 0):

Trade Gothic is not a free font. It is available for a web font license on MyFonts.com, Linotype.com and Fonts.com.

It looks like you are using an unauthorized version. If you pay for a proper web font license, you get the correct CSS font stack with the fonts, and that will solve your problem.

Comment: This is a very good point but these kind of answers could be posted as comments. I gave an upvote since the point.